# Can we replace some of the leftover "Food and Cooking" references?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, design

I hope/suspect that the actual text is only stored in one or two places, but nevertheless the "title" of our site appears in a lot of places other than the logo itself.  I'd like to see the "internal" name changed to be more consistent and less confusing.

I don't care if it says `Seasoned Advice` or `Seasoned Advice - Stack Exchange`.  I wouldn't even *really* mind if it said `Cooking - Stack Exchange` (although one of the former two would be **highly** preferable).  But I'd really like to get the word "Food" out of there as quickly as possible.  After all, our subdomain is **cooking**.stackexchange.com and not **food**.stackexchange.com for a reason.

This may sound nitpicky to some team members, but unfortunately, [some visitors](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8498/minimum-wage-whole-food-diet-closed) are still [not grokking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/whats-the-worst-that-can-happen-if-i-eat-things-that-are-too-spicy-closed) the purpose of the site, and I think it doesn't help that the phrase "Food and Cooking" is plastered all over the place.  In particular I'm concerned about:

- The actual page title that shows up in the browser's title bar.  I actually experienced this at some other, completely different site the other day (really wish I could remember which one), where the logo and contact information were inconsistent with the page title.  I was always *slightly* bothered by the inconsistency here, but seeing it happen on a totally different site that I was not already familiar with made me realize just how disconcerting it really is to a newbie.  I kept thinking *"What's going on here, what site am I actually on?"*
- The [FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq).  Since this is the first place people are going to go if they have questions about the site itself, we are liable to confuse them even more by referring to a name that they haven't seen before.
- The text under the `How to Ask` sidebar when asking a new question, which says: **Is your question about food or cooking?** Obviously we're not going to put "Seasoned Advice" in there, but the word "Food" is only going to mislead people into asking the wrong questions.  This should simply say, **Is your question about cooking?**  If some people are unhappy with this (i.e. due to thinking of cooking as being separate from baking and so on) then *cooking or food preparation* would be a better catch-all phrase.
- Finally, the meta sidebar says **Is your question about the Food and Cooking Meta - Stack Exchange community or website?** This, again, should probably refer to the name *Seasoned Advice* instead (again - if the team is concerned about branding, I don't think any of us will mind if it says *Seasoned Advice - Stack Exchange*, but please not *Food and Cooking - Stack Exchange*).

Can we get these changed in the very near future?  And if not, can we be given reasons why they would need to stay as they are?

Comment: This is carrying on as we speak: [Advice for large group snacks with small budget!](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/8572/41) and [What are some affordable packed lunch ideas that actually taste good?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8584/what-are-some-affordable-packed-lunch-ideas-that-actually-taste-good) - we're starting to see a lot of these questions lately.

Comment: I'm 100% on board with this.  I think it will significantly help those who think this is a general food advice board to stop thinking it.

Comment: Man, I really need the ability to give multiple upvotes.

Comment: I appreciate the "cooking or food preparation" suggestion - though most people wouldn't even blink, it feels a bit more right to me. (Otherwise, in total agreement.)

Comment: I just noticed that this is tagged feature-request. I think it's more correctly described as a bug, isn't it?

Comment: @Marti: Perhaps, although I doubt it'll make much of a difference with respect to if and how quickly it gets done.  Either they're working on it or they aren't.

Comment: @Aaronut: since my gripe about link highlighting was fixed within a couple of days, and this hasn't so much as gotten a response, I would conclude that the 'bug' tag gets higher priority than the 'feature-request' tag.

Comment: @Marti: Hah, maybe, although it might also depend on *who* needs to handle the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed all the "Food" strings where I could find them. This may take a server cycle (up to 24 hours) to take effect across the entire webfarm though -- we already deployed for tonight.

Comment: thank you.  Hope this helps some of our newbies!

Comment: Hey Jeff - looks like all of the obvious places are done *except* for the very first sentence of the [FAQ](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq) (all subsequent entries in the FAQ were updated).  Will it take a long time to get that straggler?

Comment: @aaro I think you have the ability to edit that FAQ as a moderator by clicking "edit" on it. I edited it anyway..

Comment: You're right, I forgot that was part of the editable section.  Thanks anyway!